# What is the correct notation for every nth term in a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

How do I denote every nth term in a sequence? For example, if sequence $C$ contains:

$C = \{ 2, 5, 3, 6, 4, 5, ...\}$

And sequence $Q$ contains every 4th term in C:

$Q = \{C_{4}, C_{8}, C_{12}...\}$

How to I express that using correct mathematical notation? In the example I have given above, $Q$ contains every 4th term - but what would be a general way to express nth term of a sequence?

My knowledge of mathematics is basic - perhaps there is a notation of which I do not know of. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: $Q_n = C_{4n}$ for all $n≥1$ ?

Comment: Ah, it appears that may be the answer. I was expecting something akin to Sigma notation - but it seems simplicity is the best. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you can define $Q_n = C_{4n}$ for every integer $n≥1$.

Comment: Looks like the OP forgot about you.  I gave you an upvote to help you out.

Comment: @GregoryGrant : thank you! Then this question won't be considered as an "unanswered question"!

Comment: Definitely didn't forget - just a bit late :). Good simple answer to a quick and simple question - thanks for the help!

Comment: @peterpacz1 : you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

As this is a question about notation, let me add that the notation you are using is for *sets* and not for sequences.  Sequences imply that there's an order while sets are by definition not ordered in any way, for example $\{1,2,3\}$ is the same set as $\{3,1,2\}$.

Sequences are typically written with parentheses as in $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ or $(a_n)$ for short.  In your case, you'd have a sequence $(c_n)$ and the other sequence would then be $(q_n)$ with $q_n=c_{4n}$, or simply $(c_{4n})$.

Also, be aware that the "$4n$ trick" will only work if your sequences start with index $n=1$.  In mathematics, $\mathbb N$ is often meant to include zero, so $(a_n)$ would mean $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)$.  But then $(a_{4n})$ would be $(a_0,a_4,a_8,\dots)$.

Comment: Thank you for rightfully pointing out that my notation was incorrect. Mathematical notation is one of my weak points, and this has been especially helpful. I've already chosen my answer, but thank you very much!